# np.where not returning expected result in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have looked through np.where examples and thought I'd cracked it, however the result I get is still not correct.
I have a data frame of football results and wish to return a 'Yes' or 'No' depending on if both home and away team has scored.
The code I have tried, returns only 'Yes' and I cannot see why?

What I expect to see is 'Yes' where 'home_team_goal_count' **and** 'away_team_goal_count' are not zero.

I have tried:

```
resultsdf['BTTS'] = np.where((resultsdf['home_team_goal_count'] == '0') | (resultsdf['away_team_goal_count'] == '0'), 'No', 'Yes')
```

Where 'BTTS' will be a new column.
This was attempted from a modified answer I had found

Then:

```
resultsdf['BTTS'] = np.where((resultsdf['home_team_goal_count'] != '0') & (resultsdf['away_team_goal_count'] != '0'), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Because I wanted to switch the emphasis on looking for non zero's, however I still only get 'Yes' returned.

Then:

```
resultsdf['BTTS'] = np.where(np.logical_and(resultsdf['home_team_goal_count'] != '0', resultsdf['away_team_goal_count'] != '0'), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Because I had come across another post which suggested to use 'np.logical' instead or '|' or '&'

All 3 ways return all 'Yes' and no 'No' in the new 'BTTS' column.

Help appreciated.

Edit:
dtype returned is as follows

```
date_GMT                          object
home_team_name                    object
away_team_name                    object
home_team_goal_count               int64
away_team_goal_count               int64
total_goal_count                   int64
home_team_goal_count_half_time     int64
away_team_goal_count_half_time     int64
total_goals_at_half_time           int64
home_team_goal_timings            object
away_team_goal_timings            object
HCS                               object
ACS                               object
HCSCount                           int64
ACSCount                           int64
BTTS                              object
dtype: object
```

Is this because the BTTS is object?

I had looked at dtype beforehand and noticed that home and away goals were both int64, so presumed BTTS would be int64 too.
Apologies if this is the issue, sometimes a simple answer is lost by looking for a more complex solution  - for me at least and something I hope to learn
How would I overcome this issue?

Edit 2:
The last few columns of the dataframe look like this
[image]

Where HCS being 'yes' would signify a clean sheet (home_team_goal_count equal to zero) and therefore, BTTS should be 'No'

Comment: Can you add some sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to question with expected output?

Comment: What's the `dtype` of the `'home_team_goal_count'` column?

Comment: I'll edit the post with the dtype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to check the `dtypes` of your data frame. 
Because the approach you have chosen must work.

```py
>>> df
   x  y
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  0
3  0  0
4  1  0
5  0  0
6  1  0
7  1  0
8  1  1
9  1  0
>>> df['result'] = np.where((df.x=='0') | (df.y == '0'), "No", "Yes")
>>> df
   x  y result
0  1  0     No
1  1  0     No
2  0  0     No
3  0  0     No
4  1  0     No
5  0  0     No
6  1  0     No
7  1  0     No
8  1  1    Yes
9  1  0     No
>>> df.dtypes
x         object
y         object
result    object
dtype: object
```

**Edit**

```
resultsdf['BTTS'] = np.where((resultsdf['home_team_goal_count'] == 0) | (resultsdf['away_team_goal_count'] == 0), 'No', 'Yes')
```

Comment: The dtype of both home and away goals is int64, whereas the BTTS is object.
Is something incorrect with that?
I have edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Then you should compare to `0` and not `'0'`

Comment: Check the updated answer